# Why CSS does not support function-like constructions?

Tags: css

I am mostly a backend programmer, and am relatively new to CSS. So far, I hate it. My biggest complain is that is incredibly redundant and difficult to produce readable code.

Many times I need to apply styling to different but similar elements. However, I find it incredibly challenging to produce elegant code to do that.

The most simple way to do things in CSS seems to be to give an ID to everything and use custom code for every single element in the page, or classes when there are repeated elements with. However, this still leaves a lot of repeated code, like when I have two elements that are almost exactly alike, but have one or two different attributes, like width, background color, color or float side.

My current solution is defining many atomic classes, like

```
.bgRed { background-color: red; }
.bgBlue { background-color: blue; }
.fontCenter { text-align:center; }
.left { float: left; }
```

and so on, and applying multiple classes to an element, like this:

```
<span class='bgRed left' >My text</span>
```

But that's still very short of decent. Some attributes, like width and height, are usually strongly tied to it's elements, so I can't create an atomic class for it, and end up resorting to using it's ID.

**Finally, my question:** Why doesn't CSS support some kind function-like structure? Would a feature like this be useful in CSS? Is CSS badly designed or I just don't know how to use it properly? Why was CSS designed the way it is?

How I imagined functions in css would work:

Defining a css function:

```
_sidebar(float_side, color, width){
    float: float_side;
    backgroud-color: color;
    width: width:
    height: 200px;
    color: #FE02A5
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
}
```

And applying:

```
<div cssfunc='sidebar(left, #FF0000, 150px)' >
    <ul>
        <li>Item One</li>
        <li>Item Two</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Bonus question: How do you maintain you CSS code readable and organized, with minimal code repetition?

Comment: you might want to take a look at some [css](http://sass-lang.com/) [preprocessors](http://lesscss.org/). they both have syntaxes similar to what you have, except for the html attribute.

Comment: SASS...http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: SASS and LESS are the answer to CSS's lack of variable structure. Coming from a programming background myself, I feel your pain, but what others have mentioned is true: CSS simply wasn't designed to work that way. Pre-processors allow a good degree of functionality, as does Javascript. (JS can be much heavier though, so if your intentions purely revolve around style, rather than function, LESS and SASS are the way to go.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the intended usage pattern for CSS.  A general clue is if you have specific formatting words like colors or alignments in your class name, you're not following the "spirit" of CSS.

The intention for CSS classes is to use semantic categories for class names.  For example instead of having a class named `bgRed`, use one called `warning`.  The difference might be subtle in some cases, but the difference in philosophy usually helps maintenance.  Instead of combining "literal" css rules at the element level, you'd combine more meaningful semantic ones like `class="sidebar warning"`.

With that said, some people still find the lack of reusability of formatting between CSS rules cumbersome.  There are fixes for that as well.  The best solution is to use a CSS pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).  These languages compile into CSS, but support things like mixins  and variables that function very much like the css enhancement you have in mind.

Comment: I didn't know there were CSS preprocessors. That's already half the battle. I'll take a better look at them, SASS seems quite interesting. Anyone knows how widespread is the use of CSS preprocessors?

Comment: I don't know specifics, but I get the sense they are quite prevalent.

Comment: @drakenation CSS prepocessors are pretty standard these days. It's rare I run into many FE devs not using them in some way.

Answer (score 3):

HTML defines what to show, CSS defines how to show it. If you use classes like "bgRed" or "left", you are doing this old way.

CSS doesn't define support functions, but LESS does. Imagine this:

```
.sidebar(@side, @color, @width) {
    float: @side;
    backgroud-color: @color;
    width: @width:
    height: 200px;
    color: #FE02A5
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
}
.sidebar-important {
    .sidebar(left, red, 100px);
}
.sidebar-misc {
    .sidebar(right, blue, 50px);
    color: grey; // overwrites .sidebar function
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar-important">Important news</div>
<div class="sidebar-misc">Something else</div>
```

This way, you can easily change values in LESS file, compile it to CSS and you won't need to change it in HTML.

Bonus answer:
LESS.